# Remove part of String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a String like

```
var str = "test\ntesttest\ntest\nstringtest\n..."
```

If I reached a configured count of lines ('\n') in the string, I want to remove the first line. That means all text to the first '\n'.

Before:

```
var str = "test1\ntesttest2\ntest3\nstringtest4\n...5"
```

After:

```
var str = "testtest2\ntest3\nstringtest4\n...5"
```

Is there a function in Javascript that I can use?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the first occurence of `\n` and return only everything after it

```
var newString = str.substring(str.indexOf("\n") + 1);
```

The `+ 1` means that you're also removing the new-line character so that the beginning of the new string is only text after the first `\n` from the original string.

Comment: it should be `str.substring(str.indexOf("\n")+1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `string.replace` function also.

```
> var str = "test1\ntesttest2\ntest3\nstringtest4\n...5"
> str.replace(/.*\n/, '')
'testtest2\ntest3\nstringtest4\n...5'
```

Comment: Which solution is more efficient? replace or substring?

Answer (score 0):

```
str.substr(str.indexOf("\n")+1)
```

str.indexOf("\n")+1 gets the index of the first character after your first linebreak.
str.substr(str.indexOf("\n")+1) gets a substring of str starting at this index

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `substring(..)` function.  It is built-in with JavaScript.  From the docs:

> The substring() method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.
>
> Usage:
>
> `mystring.substring(start,end)`

The start index is required, the end index is not.  If you omit the end index, it will substring from the start to the end of the string.

Or in your case, something like:

`str = str.substring(str.indexOf('\n')+1);`

Comment: It is helpful if you explain what the code does to the person asking the question (the Original Poster) since the OP is obviously new to JavaScript String parsing...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like this if I understand you correctly

```
function removePart(str, count) {  
    var strCount = str.split('\n').length - 1;
    if(count > strCount) {   
        var firstIndex = str.indexOf('\n');
        return str.substring(firstIndex, str.length -1);
    }
    return str;
}
```